# Rails associations one column to many objects of same type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my Rails app I have a user, product, and order table. A user can by multiple products per order. When this happens, I store the items as a string in a column (product_id) in my order table. For example, if a user buys 3 different products, the product ids will be stored in the product_id column of my order table: `product_id: "12, 97, 132"`.

I associate users to orders e.g. a user `has_many :orders` and an order `belongs_to :user`. What I want to do, for each user, is to display their previous orders and the products that were a part of that order. With the associations I can easily get the orders: `@orders = current_user.orders.all` but is there any way to associate the products with the orders since if multiple products can associated with one order?

Right now, in my orders model I have added an `attr_accessor :products` and in my controller I have:

```
  def orders
    @orders = current_user.orders.all
    @orders.each do |order|
      items = Product.find(order.product_id.split(','))
      order.products = items
    end
  end
```

This works, but is there a 'prebuilt' way to associate the orders and products if there are multiple product ids stored in the reference column?

Comment: You should avoid using `<model_name>_id` for anything that doesn't actually relate to a (single) relation id.

Answer (score 2):

You should create a join-table between `products` and `orders` and we'll call it `line_items`.

```
## app/models/product.rb
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :line_items
  has_many :orders, through: :line_items
end

## app/models/line_item.rb
class LineItem < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :order
end

## app/models/order.rb
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :line_items
  has_many :products, through: :line_items
end
```

In order to to associate the orders and products, just using built-in `has_many` like this:

```
@order = Order.first
@order.products.count # => 0

@order.product_ids = [12, 97, 132]
@order.products.count # => 3
```

Comment: Interesting. I will give it a try. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If an order has_many products and a product has_many orders, you can associate products without using the string notation you mentioned. Then you would just need a join table referencing both.

Answer (score 1):

The better way to handle your case is to create many-to-many relationship between products and orders via join table.

1 - Create orders_products table

```
class CreateOrdersProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
      create_table :orders_products do |t|
        t.references :order, index: true
        t.references :product, index: true
      end
    end
end
```

2 - In models/order.rb

```
class Order
  has_and_belongs_to_many  :products
end
```

3 - In models/product.rb

```
class Product
  has_and_belongs_to_many  :orders
end
```

After create the association, you can save products to a particular orders using:

```
order.products = products
order.save
```

Get products of particular order:

```
order.products
```